# Error while trying to read file with node js from desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Im using the following code to read simple file from my desktop

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/aa', function(req, res) {

        fs = require('fs');
        fs.readFile('‪C:\\Users\\t56789\\Desktop\\myfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data);
        });

    });
```

when I hit in the browser /aa i got the following error

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\t56789\WebstormProjects\Ro0.1\?C:\Users\t56789\Desktop\myfile.txt']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\Users\t56789\WebstormProjects\Ro0.1\?C:\Users\t56789\Desktop\myfile.txt' }
```

if I return instead `res.send("test")` i able to see in the browser test...
any idea what I miss  here ?

Comment: You're running a web server. The root of the web server is the directory it runs in. You can't directly read the C: drive. You can only read what's inside that root directory.

Comment: @JeremyThille-what does it mean running web server(express?) and if there is other way to do it? I fairly new to nodeJS...

Comment: Well NodeJS is a web server... just like Apache. If you run it from `c:/myWebsite`, Node will only be able to read what is inside `c:/myWebsite`. Only your website's files, not the whole disk. Unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: use path module to normalize path according Your OS requirements. and also read this article: http://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/

Comment: I think so. Cuz web server cannot deny You to get access to files above (it's files systems job) it's root, especially if You're using windows where Your user already is root (:

Comment: The code you are showing is not the code you are running because otherwise it would work. As you can see it says path: 'C:\Users\t56789\WebstormProjects\Ro0.1\?C:\Users\t56789\Desktop\myfile.txt' so i assume that you pass some variable to the readFile function and obviously incorrectly because C:\Users\t56789\WebstormProjects\Ro0.1\? should not be a part of the path. Make sure the code you are showing us is the very same you actualy use!

Comment: @Molda-This is exactly my code I can share it if you like and you want to help....are you sure that this is possible,I ask it becouse Jeremy answer but Im not sure that he sure ...:), btw I use webstorm and this is exactly the error message I got even when I use '‪C:\\Users\\t56789\\Desktop\\myfile.txt'

Answer (score 1):

Because of the security reasons the web server is limited to it's current directory. So if you want to reach some file move it first to the web server's directory. Just to prove the concept you could try this code:

```
app.get('/aa', function (req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile(__filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

It will display the content of the file where the code is.

Comment: Thanks but where should I configure the __filename ?

Comment: __filename is a Node.js default variable that always shows the current file path. It is not you who do the configuration. You can read more about https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html or https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: It is not possible the file to be on the desktop you must manually copy/move the file in the web server directory.