# How to get image from directory with node.js and send it to the client side to display on android app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I am using node.js on the server-side and java on the client-side (android app). On the server-side i run a query to grab data from my database and one of the columns is an image path. I want to use the image path to grab the actual image on the server side and pass it to the client-side so it can be displayed on the app.

Any idea on how to do this? Please help

Answer (score 3):

```
var fs = require('fs');
function(req,res){
  fs.readFile('image.jpg', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
      res.end(data); // Send the file data to the browser.
  });
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me, an error is thrown trying to read the file. i even tried to set the path and it still didnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660250/error-while-trying-to-read-file-with-node-js-from-desktop